# How can I retrieve the SVN Changeset comments for a Jenkins build?

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

My process is that Jenkins polls SVN for a build every three minutes, performs a build when a change occurs, and creates a deployment package which it then pushes to Octopus. Once the deployment is complete, it sends a deployment report via email to everyone involved.

Right now, the build notes in the report are just typical boilerplate, i.e., Jenkins Build 35. What would be great would be if I could pull the comments for the changeset that triggered the build and build the release notes off of that.

If I can get AT the comments, getting them into the release notes is pretty simple. If anyone has any ideas on that, I would appreciate it.

UPDATE: There is a related question about how to do this with the email-ext plugin, but I'm not using that plugin, and as far as I can tell, the answer is expressed using the syntax of that plugin and I can't figure out how to adapt it. I would appreciate an answer that bears directly on my usage here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the SVN log entry in Jenkins when sending email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444800/how-can-i-get-the-svn-log-entry-in-jenkins-when-sending-email)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 3 ways you can get the SCM changes

## Groovy

[**Groovy**](http://groovy-lang.org/) is similar to Java and is native to Jenkins, hence you can reference Jenkins object models and data directly with Groovy. You still requires plugins to execute Groovy code, such as **[Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin)**. Here is a bit of sample code adopted from this answer:
[How to get the list of changed file in SVN from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099449/how-to-get-the-list-of-changed-file-in-svn-from-jenkins)

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.*
import hudson.scm.*
import hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet.LogEntry

// work with current build
def build = Thread.currentThread()?.executable

// for testing, use last build or specific build number
//def item = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("Update_SRC_Branch") 
//def build = item.getLastBuild()   
//def build = item.getBuildByNumber(35)   

// get ChangesSets with all changed items
def changeSet= build.getChangeSet()
List<LogEntry> items = changeSet.getItems()
```

From there, the `items` list now contains the change set. Use as you wish. This is as far as I am going to go with Groovy, cause frankly I don't use it.

## Filesystem

Jenkins stores builds on the filesystem under `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/$BUILD_ID`. Prior to version 1.597, the `$BUILD_ID` was a timestamp in the format like `2015-03-16_00-13-19`. **[After version 1.597](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JENKINS-24380+Migration)**, the `$BUILD_ID` is now a build number `$BUILD_NUMBER` like `123` (same as what you see in the build history log).

There is a file there: `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/$BUILD_ID/changelog.xml`. It contains all the same SCM changesets that you see in the UI, pulled from your SCM, all in an XML file. Parse the file, and every `<msg>...</msg>` element contains the comments. There may be more than one.

However, although all the variables are available to you at runtime during the build (change `$VAR` to `%VAR%` if on Windows), the specific build location is **NOT** created till the build is completed, so you can't access it during the current build. You can however pass all these variables to a downstream build (for example your deployment job, if it is separate), and that downstream build can extract the changelog file. You would need **[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)** to pass variables to another build.

## Email

The mailer action that comes with Jenkins can do almost nothing other than the "boilerplate" message. If you want *anything* to do with emails, you need the **[Email-ext (Extended Email) Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)**. There are a ton of questions/answers on SO here about email-ext, even a tag [email-ext](/questions/tagged/email-ext), however I would advise searching for text `email-ext` rather than using a tag, as a lot of questions are not fully tagged.

Your first place to start would be the "**Content Token Reference**" on-page help (click the **<kbd>?</kbd>** icon next to that text. That lists all the possible tokens that can be used in the email title/body

You wanted the "SCM comments". Those are referenced through `%m` of `${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS}` token. To get *just* the comments, use the following:

`${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS, changesFormat=" %m<br>"}`

Just put the above line into the email body configuration. You can surround it with any plain text you want.

For a more nicely formatted output, use

`${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS, reverse=true, format="<b>Changes for Build #%n</b><br>%c<br>", changesFormat="<br>[<a href='${JENKINS_URL}/user/%a/builds'>%a</a>] - (%r) %p<br> %m<br>"}`

as referenced in the close duplicate questions I provided:
[How can I get the SVN log entry in Jenkins when sending email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444800/how-can-i-get-the-svn-log-entry-in-jenkins-when-sending-email)

### P.S.

If your requirement is "no plugins", then you need to find a different build system than Jenkins. Jenkins is an open-source project, that provides a core and a plugin for almost everything else, maintained by the open community. Everything in Jenkins is a "plugin", even the *Subversion SCM* step and *Freestyle* and *Maven* projects are "plugins". Some are bundled with the installation, most need to be added after the install.

Comment: Nah, plugins are fine - I just needed it in a different output than email. I'm using plugins all over the place. Great answer.

Comment: Some items if you take the Groovy approach: 1. This must be a System Groovy script because it accesses the Build system information. 2. As such,  it will not validate in the UI - it will complain about the import for the SVN Changeset. It will, however, execute just fine. Lastly, only check-ins which necessitate a new build will end up in that collection - if you simply edit a file and add a space, like I did, that will not show up. Edit a source file.

Comment: can you please explain syntax for  'Thread.currentThread()?.executable'
I am not familiar with '?' operator

Comment: @DavidH [Safe Navigation Operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution when using Jenkins Pipeline script. The formatting of the output here is as an HTML table. The table is put within quotation marks, in my case that is needed when sending the results to other scripts.

```
#!groovy

@NonCPS
def getChangeString(buildItem) {
    def buildChanges = ''
    if (buildItem.size() > 0) {
        def changeNbr = 1;
        buildItem.each { buildChanges += changeNbr++ + '. ' + it.msg.text() + '<br>'}
        // Escape quotation marks
        buildChanges = buildChanges.replaceAll('"','\"')
        // Replace new lines with HTML
        buildChanges = buildChanges.replaceAll('\n','<br>')
    } else {
        buildChanges += 'No changes in this build'
    }
    buildChanges
}

node(){
    stage ('deploy') {
        // work with current build
        def buildUrl = BUILD_URL
        // for testing
        //def buildUrl = "http://localhost:8082/job/job_name/167/"

        def buildXml = new XmlSlurper().parse("${buildUrl}api/xml")
        def buildCause = buildXml.action.cause.shortDescription.text()
        def buildCh = getChangeString(buildXml.changeSet.item)

        def releaseNotes = "\"<table><tr><td>Jenkins build</td><td><a href='$BUILD_URL'>$BUILD_NUMBER</a><br></td></tr><tr><td>Build cause: </td><td>$buildCause</td></tr><tr><td>Changes:</td><td>$buildCh</td><tr></table>\""
        // Set variables to null to avoid NotSerializableException
        buildXml = null
        buildCause = null
        buildCh = null
        echo "releaseNotes is $releaseNotes"
    }
}
```

You need to uncheck "Use Groovy Sandbox" for this to work.